# Read each word in text file separately

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have text file (words.text) includes lines each line have characters and equivalent words like this:

```
A = 1
B = 2
C = 3
D = 4
```

I used following code to read text file

```
     System.IO.StreamReader file =   
    new System.IO.StreamReader(@"c:\words.txt");  
    while((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)  
    {  
       System.Console.WriteLine (line);  
       counter++;  
    }
```

I need to change the value of each character (number)  by counter and saved it again in way to be like this

```
A = 3
B = 4
C = 1
D = 2
```

I thought about makes each word and = to be "first" and number is "second", and loop the second one

```
First = "A = ", Second = "1"
```

I have no idea how to make program to read each line and identified first and second one

Comment: it seems you are shifting numbers, am I right?

Answer (score 2):

You can simply split each line value by `=` character to get first and second value:

```
  System.IO.StreamReader file =   
    new System.IO.StreamReader(@"c:\words.txt");  
    while((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)  
    {  
       string[] split = line.Split('=');
       string First = split[0] + " = ";
       string Second = split[1]; 
       //actually you can use split[0] and split[1], the two above llines are for demo
       counter++;  
    }
```

Comment: Don't forget to use `Trim()` to avoid unexpected spaces, especially here : `string First = split[0] + " = ";` or your `Replace` wont work. You could consider to do `string First = split[0].Trim() + " = ".
`

Comment: OK, I checked it its ok when saving but how about changing position?? If I need to Shifting all "Second" by 3 to become (A = 3 B = 4 C = 1 D = 2)??

Answer (score 1):

How about this...

```
// Getting content of the file.
string contents = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\test.txt");

// Separating content           
string[] contentArr  = contents.Split('\n');            

List<string> characterList = new List<string>();
List<int> valueList = new List<int>();

foreach (string value in contentArr)
{
    characterList.Add(string.Join("", value.ToCharArray().Where(Char.IsLetter)).Trim());
    valueList.Add(Int32.Parse(string.Join("", value.ToCharArray().Where(Char.IsDigit))));
}
```

All the characters will be stored in the characterList as a string and all the value will be stored in the valueList as integers (int).

If you need to read or change values, you can do it like this using a forloop (or a foreach).

```
for (int i = 0; i < contentArr.Length; i++)
{
    //valueList[i] = 5
    Console.WriteLine(characterList[i] + " = " + valueList[i]);
}

//// characters 
//foreach(string value in characterList)
//{
//  Console.WriteLine(value);
//}

//// Values
//foreach(int value in valueList)
//{
//  Console.WriteLine(value);
//}
```

Or, you can change value individually...

```
valueList[0] = 3;
valueList[1] = 4;
valueList[2] = 1;
valueList[3] = 2;
```

After making changes, you can write back to the file.

```
string output = "";

for (int i = 0; i < contentArr.Length; i++)
{
    output += characterList[i] + " = " + valueList[i] + Environment.NewLine;
}

File.WriteAllText(@"C:\test.txt", output);
```

Online Sample 01: http://rextester.com/TIVM24779
Online Sample 02: http://rextester.com/KAUG79928

Comment: if I use text instead of number how the code work???

Comment: In the first code, you have to change this. (line 8)
List<string> valueList = new List<string>();

Also, you have to change this too. (line 13)
valueList.Add(string.Join("", value.ToCharArray().Where(Char.IsLetter)).Trim());

Comment: In the seocond code, you don't have to change anything.
But, In the third code, you have assigned value inside of the Quotation Marks.
Example: valueList[0] = "3";
Again in the final code, you don't have to change anything.

Comment: I write the code as in below

Comment: I modified it as you say

Comment: List<string> Second = new List<string>();

      foreach (string value in contentArr)
       {
        First.Add(string.Join("", value.ToCharArray().Where(Char.IsLetter)).Trim());
         Second.Add(string.Join("", value.ToCharArray().Where(Char.IsLetter)).Trim());
        }

Comment: I have text file have characters and words (A = the
B = be
C = to
D = of

Comment: when run code it become

Comment: Athe = AtheBbe = BbeCto = CtoDof = DofEand = EandFare =

Comment: Check these two samples. 
http://rextester.com/TIVM24779 and http://rextester.com/KAUG79928

Comment: see this result

Comment: Athe = abc
Bbe = xyz
Cto = qwe
Dof = mlp

Comment: Okay. How should it be changed? What is the expected result?
(If you want to break line in the text file, add "Environment.NewLine".

Comment: I need it just shifted words after "=" see

Comment: if (A = the B = be C = to D = of) and I need counter to shifting it by 3

Comment: then the result should be

Comment: (A = be  B = to C = of  D = the )